# $\langle f, \phi_n \rangle = 0 \implies f = 0$ is equivalent to the definition of orthonormal basis

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Is there an "easy" way to see that if $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a set of orthonormal functions in a Hilbert space then showing $\langle f, \phi_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n$ implies $f = 0$ is sufficient to show that the orthonormal set is dense?

I know this statement is true because I found it as a theorem in Stein & Sharkarchi, but their proof is fairly involved.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt maybe?

Comment: Can we extend the spirit of that to infinite-dimensional spaces?

Comment: Yes. Just do the process one step at a time, and take a limit. I think that should work...

Comment: I believe you are taking about a "complete orthonormal system".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a result about orthogonal complements than orthonormal systems. There are two basic results used here, which are moderately intuitive:
(i) $(A^\bot)^\bot = \operatorname{\overline{sp}}  A$.
(ii) If $D$ is a set whose linear span is dense in $A$, then $x \in A^\bot$ **iff** $x \in D^\bot$.

Let $S = \operatorname{\overline{sp}} \{ \phi_k \}$. Then $\langle f, \phi_k \rangle = 0$ for all $k$ **iff** $f \in S^\bot$.

If $\operatorname{{sp}} \{ \phi_k \}$ is dense, then $S = \mathbb{H}$ and so
$S^\bot = \{0\}$, hence if $\langle f, \phi_k \rangle = 0$ for all $k$, we have
$f \in S^\bot$ and so $f = 0$.

Now suppose that if $\langle f, \phi_k \rangle = 0$ for all $k$, then $f=0$. Then
this implies that $S^\bot = \{0\}$. Since $(A^\bot)^\bot = \operatorname{\overline{sp}}  A$, we see that $\{0\}^\bot = \mathbb{H} = S$ ($S$ is
a closed subspace).

Comment: Alternatively (but nearly equivalently), if $M$ is any closed subspace of $V$ then $V = M \oplus M^{\perp}$.

Comment: Yes, in fact, $V = (\operatorname{\overline{sp}}  A) \oplus A^\bot$ for any set $A\subset V$.

Comment: To clarify notation, $\overline{\mathrm{sp}}\ A$ denotes the smallest closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ that contains $A$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$